# "Almost" prime k-tuples in intervals

Tags: nt.number-theory

In [this](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FMTK%2FMTK44_02%2FS0025579300012584a.pdf&code=4a079ec76ca1915f8eb4aa14d4bda045) paper, Heath-Brown proves that there are $ \gg x(\log{x})^{-k}$ integers $n \leq x$ such that $$ \prod_{i=1}^{k} (a_{i}x + b_{i}) $$ is squarefree and that each term has a "small" number of prime factors (assuming the $a_{i}x + b_{i}$'s satisfy his Hypothesis $1$, or more colloquially the set of functions is admissible).

My question is if anything can be said about how large $x$ has to be relative to the $a_{i}, b_{i}$'s in order for the result to "kick in." That is, for instance, suppose for all $i$ that $a_{i} = 1$ and that $b_{i}$ if of size $\mathcal{O}(M)$.  We know for $x$ suitably large there are $\geq cx(\log{x})^{-k}$ integers $n \leq x$ giving the desired property. Can "suitably large" be expressed as a function of $M$? (or are there any similar results in which this is done?)